# phpmyadmin import csv with symbols

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

When I import my CSV file, symbols (such as $ £ é á ü etc) are changed to ?s.

Any idea how to fix this?

(for instance can I open it in excel and save with the symbols changed to their respective html entity? eg: £ -> £)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to convert the characters into HTML entities. You just need to choose the correct character set when importing the file.

In phpMyAdmin, you should have a drop-down selection like this:

[image]

You should be able to find  out the character set used by Excel in the "Save as..." dialog.

Comment: aha! brilliant. Took a bit of research, but I chose Latin1. :) Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Thanks for giving out the encoding you used.  I had been struggling to find a way to set ISO 8559-1 as charset, didn't realise latin1 would work for me too.

Comment: @Pekka: Why doesn't UTF-8 show accented characters like `é À`? While saving excel, it is encoding as UTF-8(unicode).  When I use Latin1, I have problems with characters like `Σ, σ` and `≤` etc.  Isn't there a way where I can import data containing a mixture of all these characters?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr UTF-8 can deal with all those characters. What are you getting in place of `é` and `À`?

Comment: I get **plain** question marks like this `?`.  Interesting thing is that if I run an insert query for such strings,  they are inserted fine,  its only import that is causing problems.

Comment: Same here. This is really aggravating because if Excel is exporting a CSV WITH these characters, then one would assume it's in some kind of universal encoding that other programs would understand. I've tried several export/import formats with no luck.